# Collaborative Policy creation software

Tags: policy

Does anyone know of any collaborative policy creation software?

Preferably with an aim towards mass collaboration. I understand that SharePoint or even Microsoft word could be used for this aim but I'm looking for web software.

Comment: You do understand that Sharepoint is web/cloud software right?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [Software Recommendations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I thought politics people would be better suited to the question. Also SharePoint is not what I'm looking for as i'm not trying mass edit a word document. I've done a bit of research and I'm fairly sure what i'm looking for doesn't exist. As nearly all political software is based on electioneering and campaigning. This would be different.  At the moment everyone who makes policy seems to gave unique ways of creating it through lengthy conversations and face to face meetings and then publishes it as a document. I'm talking about converting the meetings into chatrooms upvotes etc done online.

Comment: There is more to SharePoint that document sharing and Word/Excel Document collaboration.

Comment: @Chad - the subject is suited but I would expect the question as stated would be closed on SR.SE as poor quality.

Comment: I agree the question is very poor quality. But i also think it's my first on stack exchange and i think it was posted in error (this was actually a draft).I do agree that share point can be used for a lot but i should have dismissed it with reasons in the original question. Liquidfeedback seems to have the exact fundamentals I am looking for. I just need to investigate it now.

Comment: @StephenCrowley - SR.SE has extremely stringent quality requirements.

Comment: I don't know if this is the right place but I'm glad you asked.  I've been wanting to start a website to do exactly this.  I would like to propose policies and have people respond regarding their utility and their pros and cons in order to 'crowd-source' issues and their possible consequences.  While I understand the nature of the stackexchange sites I have often found questions and answers that are 'off-topic' (because there is no 'suitable' site) that are still useful and informative.

Comment: @StephenCrowley, what did sort of project did you have in mind?

Comment: It was for policy creation and approval for a political party in ireland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Liquid Feedback](http://liquidfeedback.org/) is such a software.

It allows users to create proposals which other people can then support, oppose, or suggest changes to. People can also signal their support only under the condition that a one of the change suggestions is incorporated into the proposal.

The software was used for the internal decision-making process of the Pirate Party of Germany (although the policy proposals made there are not binding) and also used by the regional government of [the district of Friesland in Germany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friesland_(district)) under the name "Liquid Friesland"